# Calling methods in other models in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I'm pretty new to the concept of offloading functionality that affects the DB into a model instead of a controller and having some difficulty getting it to work.

Basically, from my `Stock` controller, I'm trying to call a method in my `User` model.  Instead, I'm getting an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `stock_relationships' for #<Class:0x007fc0da1a8d60>):
  app/models/user.rb:27:in `follow_stock'
  app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:20:in `add_stock'
```

So, here is what I have:

> A user adds a stock in views/stocks/index.html.erb

```
<% @stocks.each do |s| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= s.symbol %></td>
    <td><%= s.name %></td>
    <td>
       <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>"), add_stock_path(id: s.id) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

> Which then triggers the StockController `add_stock` method:

```
def add_stock
    stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    user = current_user.id
    User.follow_stock(stock_id: stock, user_id: user)
    flash[:success] = "Successfully added stock"
    redirect :back
end
```

> The 3rd line in the method is where my problem is, since the `follow_stock` method resides in the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :stock_relationships
  has_many :stocks, through: :stock_relationships

  def self.follow_stock(stock)
    self.stock_relationships.create(stock_id: stock)
  end
end
```

Can some one help me wrap my head around how to actually call this method or am I totally off base with how I'm trying it?

**UPDATE**

I've changed some code around and now I am able to create the `StockRelationship` however, `stock_id` is being saved as `nil`:

```
=> #<StockRelationship:0x007fee03f25f00
 id: 17,
 user_id: 1,
 stock_id: nil,
 created_at: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 13:44:52 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 13:44:52 UTC +00:00>
```

I changed the code in `StockController#add_stock`:

```
def add_stock
    stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow_stock(stock)
    flash[:success] = "Successfully added stock"
    redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: `#stock_relationships` is an instance method, and you are calling it on `User` class, but not on `User` instances, that is the problem. Change `def self.follow_stock(stock)` to `def follow_stock(stock)`. And call like `user.follow_stock(stock)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gradually make your code concise by refactoring.

First, let's write the implementation in controller:

```
def add_stock
  stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
  current_user.stock_relationships.create(stock: stock)
  flash[:success] = "Successfully added stock"
  redirect :back
end
```

That's not too much code, and is concise enough. In my opinion, I don't think the code needs refactoring, but if you insist on putting the logic to the `User` model to enhance the expressiveness, like

```
def add_stock
  stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
  current_user.follow_stock(stock)
  flash[:success] = "Successfully added stock"
  redirect :back
end
```

then we need to implement the `User#follow_stock`. Notice I used `#` in the notation, which means `follow_stock` should be an instance method, not a class method.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def follow_stock(stock)
    stock_relationships.create(user: self)
  end
end
```

I just did some copy and paste (evil? not in refactoring phase.), and replaced `current_user` with `self`, and it's done.

Comment: Very helpful!  Ok, the only thing is that I'm not altering the `Stock` table, instead it's the `StockRelationship` table... it's somewhat like 'following' in Twitter.  So, at this point, the `StockRelationship` gets created, however the `stock_id` is `nil`.  I'm amending the code above to illustrate.

Comment: Alright, got it working after the above refactor (with some tweaks since I'm really dealing with StockRelationship):  `stock_relationships.create(stock_id: stock.id)` ends up adding the stock_id to the DB.

Comment: Sorry for that. I updated my answer. It's 22:00 now in China, and I'm a little sleepy :)

Answer (score 0):

stock_relationships is defined on an instance of User. It looks like you are trying to call it on User in your model here

```
self.stock_relationships.create(stock_id: stock)
```

Comment: so instead of `user = current_user.id` in `StockController` I need to do: `user = User.find(current_user.id)` ?

Comment: @Godzilla74 it would be easier to answer problems with a more narrow scope, fix an error, and get to the next one

Comment: @nikkypx that's what I'm trying to do... this is the first error I've encountered related to this.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling instance method on the class, you need something like this.

```
#user.rb
def follow_stock(stock)
  self.stock_relationships.create(stock_id: stock)
end
#and from controller call it like
user.follow_stock(stock)
```

Now, it your method becomes instance method which you can call by an instance of the user class.

Comment: I often omit `self.` in such cases, but that's just a matter of favor.

Comment: @Aetherus, yeah its the matter of choice.